# Transportation problem with additional constraints

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to implement a transportation problem using [PuLP](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/) package. In my case, its a slightly modified and has additional constraints.
Lets say there are 7 suppliers [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7] and 6 destinations [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6].
Demand for every destination is 1. supply is for each supplier is 3.

So far the implementation:

```
capacity=3
suppliers,targets = cost.shape
    objective = LpProblem("Optimize_allocation",LpMinimize)
    x = LpVariable.dicts("assignment", product(range(suppliers), range(targets)), 0, 1)
    objective += lpSum(cost[i, j] * x[i, j] for i in range(suppliers) for j in range(targets))
    
    for j in range(targets):
        condition1 = lpSum( x[i, j] for i in range(suppliers)) == 1
        objective+= condition1
    for i in range(suppliers):
        condition2 = lpSum(x[i, j] for j in range(targets)) <= capacity
        objective+= condition2  
    
    objective.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))
```

Additional constraints I have are, destinations (d3,d4) will only accept goods from only one supplier(could be any one of those) and this supplier should only serve them and not serve to any other destinations.
If I combine them to one destination with demand 2 and average the cost that would work but how do I ensure the later part of the constraint? This is just an example case but in my actual problem, there could be multiple destinations that group among themselves and demand the same constraint example: (d1,d2) and (d5,d6,d3).

EDIT:
Updated to the following working code based on @kabdulla's answer but the last constraint is changed.

```
suppliers = 10
targets = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
grps = [['A','B','C'],['D'],['E'],['F','G'],['H','I']] #constraint groups
groups = [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] #constraint group ids
capacities = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2]
capacity = 3
cost = np.random.rand(suppliers,len(targets))
objective = LpProblem("Optimize_allocation",LpMinimize)
x = LpVariable.dicts("assignment1", product(range(suppliers), range(len(targets))), 0, 1,'Integer')
y = LpVariable.dicts("assignment2", product(range(suppliers), range(len(groups))), 0, 1,'Integer')
objective += lpSum(cost[i, j] * x[i, j] for i in range(suppliers) for j in range(len(targets)))

    
for j in range(len(targets)):
    objective+= lpSum( x[i, j] for i in range(suppliers)) == 1
     
    
for i in range(suppliers):
    objective+= lpSum(x[i, j] for j in range(len(targets))) <= capacity
     

for i in range(suppliers):
    for k in range(len(groups)):
        objective += lpSum(x[i,j] for j in groups[k]) <= y[i,k]*capacities[k]
        
    
for k in range(len(groups)):
    objective += lpSum(y[i,k] for i in range(suppliers)) == 1


for i in range(suppliers):
    objective+= lpSum(y[i, j] for j in range(len(groups))) <= 1

objective.solve()
```

Comment: Your code has a few problems with it (I'll leave you to debug those yourself). The reason the model isn't solving however is due to a slight issue with pulp which is that it doesn't warn you when you use the same variable name twice. In your case you have used `assignment` for both the `x` and `y` variables. If you `print(objective)` you'll see this issue - as well as some of the other bugs you have. Good luck!

Comment: Also note that the constraints I've listed in my answer are the additional ones required for the exclusive supply sets - you'll still need the other constraints to ensure demands are satisfied, and that suppliers can only supply up to their capacities.

Comment: @kabdulla I have corrected the errors I made. The solver still returned '-1'. x and y had non-integer values even though they are defined to be integers. I have changed the last constraint you mentioned in your answer to a different constraint. Look at the question, I edited with working code. This constraint change I made fixed it. My problem is solved. I think you should change the last constraint in your answer. I am gonna accept your answer either way. Go through my code if you find something wrong let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your last constraint is doing what you think it is. Please note that in my constraints `M` and `N` should be different. With `capacities` defined the way you have, `N = [sum(capacities) - i for i in capacities]` should create the `N` values I was thinking of (see my original answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First an observation - your `x[i, j]` variables (qty to supply from supplier `i` to target `j`) are continuous - suggesting that a fraction of a unit can be shipped. If that's not the intention these `x` need to be made integer (`cat='Integer'` in call to `LpVariable.dicts()`).

If I understand your additional constraints correctly there exist some "exclusive supply" sets `E_k` of target nodes. Within one of these sets:

- All supply must come from a single supplier node
- That supplier must not provide to any node outside of the set

To enforce this kind of logic you are going to need some binary variables (if your `x` variables are non-continuous and limited to range [0,1] (i.e. they are binary) you might be able to use them directly). I'll assume your `x` are continuous as given.

One way to solve this would be to introduce new binary variables `y[i, k]` which are 1 iff supplier `i` is the chosen exclusive supplier to set `k`.

Assuming you had also declared a list-of-lists of target nodes which belong to the same exlusive supply sets `E` you could add required constraints something like this:

```
for i in suppliers:
    for k in range(len(E)):
        objective += lpSum(x[i,j] for j in E[k]) <= y[i, k]*M[k]
```

Where `M[k]` are sufficiently large that they don't add additional constraints when `y[i,k]` is 1 (for example this could just be the sum of demands of nodes in the `k`th exclusive supply set.

Then you can enforce required constraints on the `y[i,k]` variables - i.e. each set `k` must have only one supplier to it:

```
for k in range(len(E)):
    objective += lpSum(y[i, k] for i in suppliers) == 1
```

And finally you'd need to add the constraint that if supplier `i` is serving exclusive set `k` (i.e. `y[i,k] == 1`) that they are not allowed supply any nodes not in that set:

```
for i in suppliers:
    for k in range(len(E)):
        objective += lpSum(x[i, j] for j in targets if j not in E[k]) <= \
                       (1 - y[i,k])*N[k]
```

Where `N[k]` are sufficiently large that they don't add additional constraints when `y[i,j] == 0` (for example could be the sum of demands of nodes not in the `k`th exclusive supply set.

Comment: thanks for the reply. variable dict x is an integer, not a continuous variable my mistake. I tried your way to update the question with code based on your answer. I used the same thing for M and N. The PuLLP did not solve the problem. Could you have a look and see what went wrong?
I only used the constraints of your answer and dropped the previous constraints i was using.